# MongoDB Realm issue: schema for namespace (tracker.users) must include partition key "_partition"

Tags: arrays, mongodb, realm

I'm trying to add a list of friends to each user as a property.  But, I don't know why I get this error: MongoDB Realm issue: schema for namespace (tracker.users) must include partition key "_partition". For my project, tasks.users, I have the id, user_id, and name, with the friends list that will contain all three as well.

```
{
  "title": "User",
  "required": [
    "_id",
    "user_id",
    "name"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "_id": {
      "bsonType": "objectId"
    },
    "user_id": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "name": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "_partion": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "friends": {
      "bsonType": [
        "array"
      ],
      "uniqueItems": true,
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "items": {
        "bsonType": [
          "object"
        ],
        "required": [
          "id"
        ],
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "description": "'items' must contain the stated fields.",
        "properties": {
          "name": {
             "bsonType": "string"
          },
          "id": {
            "bsonType": "objectId"
          },
          "user_id": {
            "bsonType": "string"
          },
          "rank": { "bsonType": "int" },
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's always a good idead to include the actual objects from your code instead of what they contain - that gives us a more clear picture of the issue. Also, tagging your question with your platform (Swift etc) is also a help.

Comment: Wdym by the objects? Sorry, i'm kind of new to this. Thanks so much!

Comment: Objects means your code, also known as your model. In Swift for example, see the [Realm Getting Started Guide](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#getting-started) and note the very first piece of code with the `class Dog: Object {` - that's a 'model' in Swift. That tells us what your objects look like whereas the JSON is the data they contain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the BETA  MongoDB Ream Sync, your objects need to include a partition key property

> MongoDB Realm uses partition keys to map MongoDB documents in a synced
> MongoDB Atlas cluster into Realm objects in realms.

You likely defined a partition key when you set up Sync in the MongoDB Realm console. Every object that you want sync'd need to contain that.

This is a really good read on how to use partition keys

[Partition Atlas Data into Realms](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sync/partitioning/#partitioning)